# ListView is reloading its items each time I scroll which I dont want

Tags: android, listview

I created a list view in android and I want to do something like each time I click on a list item it has to toggle its colour between red and green. I was able to achieve this, but the problem is that each time I scroll the listview up or down it is reloading the list items again and again and the toggled colors are being lost.

I tried using a toggle button rather than just manually adjusting the color, but even this is losing its state. When user clicks it, it turns to on state and when user scrolls up or down it is losing its state and showing off state.

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
package bk.acs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView listView;
        final String chars[] = new String[20];
        final int arr[]=new int[20];
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            chars[i]="15BEC058"+i;
        }
        Arrays.fill(arr,1);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.row);
        MyAdapter adapter =new MyAdapter(this,chars);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                arr[i]=(arr[i]==0)?(1):(0);
             String res=(arr[i]==0)?("Absent"):("Present");
                if(arr[i]==0)
                {
                    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.item_red));
                        }
                    });
                }
                if(arr[i]==1)
                {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.item_green));
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Marked "+chars[i]+" as "+res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my adapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    View row;
    TextView tv;
    String titles[];
    public MyAdapter(Context context , String[] titles )
    {
        super(context,R.layout.reg_li,R.id.reg_no,titles);
        this.titles=titles;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position , View controlView , ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_li,parent,false);
        tv=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.reg_no);
        tv.setText(titles[position]);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us you're pasting your code. Now, WHERE is it?

Comment: now I kept code please see it...

Comment: Clarify question and bring in external code into question itself.

Comment: Actually I tried to paste the code here itself but the textbox is not pasting the full code...It is removing some part of it so I kept url.....

Answer (score 0):

To do this thing, you need to declare a boolean variable which is set to false by default. When you click any particular item, get the position of item, and set the value of boolean variable to true, it will help you to get your result.

Comment: by default it was set as false but please suggest me how to make it true

Comment: if you used the POJO class to store your data/values then decleare new boolean type variable when you stores the data into your pojo class set boolean variable false and whenever you select the item in your listview get the position of item and set that posiiton boolean true

Answer (score 0):

Use Viewholder for listview android set colors on your adapter class only

```
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
       String [] result;
    Context context;
       int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

 public Myadapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity;
   imageId=prgmImages;
   inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return result.length;
      }

      @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
      }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return position;
    }

 public class Holder
    {
 TextView tv_language;
   ImageView im_language;
    }
   @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Holder holder=new Holder();
      View view;
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_language_list_item, null);

   holder.tv_language=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_language);
    holder.im_language=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

      holder.tv_language.setText(result[position]);
  Picasso.with(context).load(imageId[position]).into(holder.image);

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   //your color change if loop should come here

}
 });
   return view;
   }

  }
```

The above adapter is for a listview contains one imageview and a textview.You need to give your color change code in onclick listener .i mentioned the place in comment.

Comment: bro I really appreciate your idea of adding listeners during runtime.But that have't worked for me either.Here is my code please have a look at this https://bharath-koteswarao.github.io/da1/code.html

Comment: You need to use an adapter with a holder class as shown in the above code. And onlcik should be given to holder view. You are still giving onclick to listitem in main activity itself and not using viewholder class. Please refer the above tutorial for knowing more about list items with viewholder class